# How to push xml object to array?

Tags: php, xml

I want to push each coa to array.here is the xml file code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<companies>
    <company>
        <name>Best Western</name>
        <groups>
            <group>
                <coa>410101 · Net Room Revenue Taxable</coa>
                <coa>415101 · GTD No Show</coa>
                <coa>Total 400000 · ROOM REVENUE</coa>
                <coa>Total I · ROOM REVENUE</coa>
                <coa>II · OTHER OPERATING REVENUE</coa>
                <coa>425120 · Meeting Room</coa>
                <coa>480380 · Interest Income</coa>
                <coa>480383 · Guest Laundry</coa>
                <coa>480385 · Vending</coa>
                <coa>480389 · Miscellaneous</coa>
                <coa>482000 · Sales Tax Discounts</coa>
                <coa>Total 480000 · OTHER INCOME</coa>
                <coa>Total II · OTHER OPERATING REVENUE</coa>
                <coa>Total Income</coa>
            </group>
            <group>
                <coa>10 · ROOMS DEPARTMENT</coa>
                <coa>Total Income</coa>
            </group>
        </groups>
    </company>
</companies>
```

Now i have tried this code

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
foreach ($xml as $company) {
$groups = $company->groups;
    $coa_list = $groups->group;
    $coa_array = array();
    foreach ($coa_list as $coal) {
        $coa_array = array();
        $coa_k = $coal->coa;
        foreach ($coa_k as $key => $value) {
            $val = $value;
            array_push($coa_array, $val);
        }
    }
}
```

Actually it should work but i dont know why but its not working.

Note: I am reading the xml file.

When i will print $val before array push, it will print but cannot push it into array.

So can You suggest me what is the issue with my code

Thanks

Comment: You're resetting the array at each loop. You don't wanna do that. Define `$coa_array = array();` outside the `foreach`

Comment: I have do that 
But same result

Comment: Do you want all `coa` values from every group in one array? Or do you want coas from the same group to be within their own array?

Comment: I have also moved the `$coa_array` declarations (both of them) outside the foreach and your code is working for me.

Comment: want coas from the same group to be within their own array

Comment: Ok I wrote a solution that returns an array of coa groups.  After reading the longest answer below another question came to mind though: do you expect the resulting array members to be SimpleXml objects? or just the values extracted from the xml source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File example.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<companies>
    <company>
        <name>Best Western</name>
        <groups>
            <group>
                <coa>410101 · Net Room Revenue Taxable</coa>
                <coa>415101 · GTD No Show</coa>
                <coa>Total 400000 · ROOM REVENUE</coa>
                <coa>Total I · ROOM REVENUE</coa>
                <coa>II · OTHER OPERATING REVENUE</coa>
                <coa>425120 · Meeting Room</coa>
                <coa>480380 · Interest Income</coa>
                <coa>480383 · Guest Laundry</coa>
                <coa>480385 · Vending</coa>
                <coa>480389 · Miscellaneous</coa>
                <coa>482000 · Sales Tax Discounts</coa>
                <coa>Total 480000 · OTHER INCOME</coa>
                <coa>Total II · OTHER OPERATING REVENUE</coa>
                <coa>Total Income</coa>
            </group>
            <group>
                <coa>10 · ROOMS DEPARTMENT</coa>
                <coa>Total Income</coa>
            </group>
        </groups>
    </company>
</companies>
```

Here is the php code for fetching coa for you have to convert the simplexmlobject to array.

```
<?php
    $xml = simplexml_load_file('example.xml');

    // echo "<pre>";
    // print_r($xml);
    // echo "</pre>";

    $coa_array = array(); 
    foreach ($xml as $company) { 
        $groups = $company->groups;
        $coa_list = $groups->group;    
        foreach ($coa_list as $coal) {
            $coa_k = $coal->coa;
            foreach ($coa_k as $key => $value) {
                $val = xml2array($value);
                // echo "<pre>";
                // print_r($val[0]);
                // echo "</pre>";
                // $val[]
                array_push($coa_array, $val[0]);
            }
        }
    }

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($coa_array);
    echo "</pre>";

    function xml2array( $xmlObject, $out = array () ){
        foreach ( (array) $xmlObject as $index => $node )
            $out[$index] = ( is_object ( $node ) ) ? xml2array ( $node ) : $node;

        return $out;
    }
?>
```

Result Will be

```
Array
(
    [0] => 410101 · Net Room Revenue Taxable
    [1] => 415101 · GTD No Show
    [2] => Total 400000 · ROOM REVENUE
    [3] => Total I · ROOM REVENUE
    [4] => II · OTHER OPERATING REVENUE
    [5] => 425120 · Meeting Room
    [6] => 480380 · Interest Income
    [7] => 480383 · Guest Laundry
    [8] => 480385 · Vending
    [9] => 480389 · Miscellaneous
    [10] => 482000 · Sales Tax Discounts
    [11] => Total 480000 · OTHER INCOME
    [12] => Total II · OTHER OPERATING REVENUE
    [13] => Total Income
    [14] => 10 · ROOMS DEPARTMENT
    [15] => Total Income
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Cool trick: `json_encode` can encode SimpleXml objects, and `json_decode` can be used to transform them into an array:

```
$json = json_encode(simplexml_load_string($url));
$array = json_decode($json,true);
$coaGroups = array_column($array['company']['groups']['group'],'coa');
```

[**Live demo**](https://3v4l.org/79CX9)

Comment: Superb solution so much of code in just three line :) kudos.

Comment: Thanks for the kind words. Glad it helped. If it's your chosen solution, then select it as your answer. If not, select another.

Answer (score 0):

problem is with the array declaration.because each time it will create same array with the same name since its inside for loop,make array declaration dynamic

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the array declarations outside the code:

File **test.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<companies>
    <company>
        <name>Best Western</name>
        <groups>
            <group>
                <coa>410101 · Net Room Revenue Taxable</coa>
                <coa>415101 · GTD No Show</coa>
                <coa>Total 400000 · ROOM REVENUE</coa>
                <coa>Total I · ROOM REVENUE</coa>
                <coa>II · OTHER OPERATING REVENUE</coa>
                <coa>425120 · Meeting Room</coa>
                <coa>480380 · Interest Income</coa>
                <coa>480383 · Guest Laundry</coa>
                <coa>480385 · Vending</coa>
                <coa>480389 · Miscellaneous</coa>
                <coa>482000 · Sales Tax Discounts</coa>
                <coa>Total 480000 · OTHER INCOME</coa>
                <coa>Total II · OTHER OPERATING REVENUE</coa>
                <coa>Total Income</coa>
            </group>
            <group>
                <coa>10 · ROOMS DEPARTMENT</coa>
                <coa>Total Income</coa>
            </group>
        </groups>
    </company>
</companies>
```

**The php code**

```
<?php
$xml  = simplexml_load_file("test.xml");

$coa_array = array(); 
foreach ($xml as $company) { 
    $groups = $company->groups;
    $coa_list = $groups->group;    
    foreach ($coa_list as $coal) {
        $coa_k = $coal->coa;
        foreach ($coa_k as $key => $value) {
            $val = $value;
            array_push($coa_array, $val);
        }
    }
}

print_r($coa_array);
```

Prints:

```
Array
(
    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [0] => 410101 · Net Room Revenue Taxable
        )

    [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [0] => 415101 · GTD No Show
        )

    [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [0] => Total 400000 · ROOM REVENUE
        )

    [3] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [0] => Total I · ROOM REVENUE
        )

    [4] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [0] => II · OTHER OPERATING REVENUE
        )

    [5] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [0] => 425120 · Meeting Room
        )

    [6] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [0] => 480380 · Interest Income
        )

    [7] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [0] => 480383 · Guest Laundry
        )

    [8] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [0] => 480385 · Vending
        )

    [9] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [0] => 480389 · Miscellaneous
        )

    [10] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [0] => 482000 · Sales Tax Discounts
        )

    [11] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [0] => Total 480000 · OTHER INCOME
        )

    [12] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [0] => Total II · OTHER OPERATING REVENUE
        )

    [13] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [0] => Total Income
        )

    [14] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [0] => 10 · ROOMS DEPARTMENT
        )

    [15] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [0] => Total Income
        )

)
```

If you want to have each group create a new entry in the array you can modify the code as follows:

```
<?php
$xml  = simplexml_load_file("test.xml");

$group_array = array(); 
foreach ($xml as $company) { 
    $groups = $company->groups;
    $coa_list = $groups->group;    
    foreach ($coa_list as $coal) {
        $coa_k = $coal->coa;
        $coa_array = [];
        foreach ($coa_k as $key => $value) {
            $val = $value;
            array_push($coa_array, $val);
        }
        array_push($group_array, $coa_array);
    }
}

print_r($group_array);
```

Prints:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [0] => 410101 · Net Room Revenue Taxable
                )

            [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [0] => 415101 · GTD No Show
                )

            [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [0] => Total 400000 · ROOM REVENUE
                )

            [3] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [0] => Total I · ROOM REVENUE
                )

            [4] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [0] => II · OTHER OPERATING REVENUE
                )

            [5] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [0] => 425120 · Meeting Room
                )

            [6] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [0] => 480380 · Interest Income
                )

            [7] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [0] => 480383 · Guest Laundry
                )

            [8] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [0] => 480385 · Vending
                )

            [9] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [0] => 480389 · Miscellaneous
                )

            [10] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [0] => 482000 · Sales Tax Discounts
                )

            [11] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [0] => Total 480000 · OTHER INCOME
                )

            [12] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [0] => Total II · OTHER OPERATING REVENUE
                )

            [13] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [0] => Total Income
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [0] => 10 · ROOMS DEPARTMENT
                )

            [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [0] => Total Income
                )

        )

)
```